# Twitch API Checking if a Channel is Live

Tags: php, twitch

I found a way to check if a channel is live on Twitch. I have been getting a error, "Trying to get property of non-object" for the "return ( ! is_null( $Request->stream ) ) ? TRUE : FALSE;" line. Everything seems set. I would appreciate any suggestions/help.

```
    <?php
function is_channel_live( $channel ) {
    $Request = json_decode( @file_get_contents( 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' . $channel ) );
    return ( ! is_null( $Request->stream ) ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

if (is_channel_live("thegamingbelugas")) {
    echo "LIVE";
}

?>
```

Comment: First of all, you can't request to twitch (from arround august) without a `client_id` in you request

Answer (score 0):

Use `$request` with lowercase:

```
$request = json_decode( @file_get_contents( 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' . $channel ) );
return ( ! is_null( $request->stream ) ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

instead of `$Request`. Twitch API doesn't understand the uppercase Request.

You also need a client ID for twitch API connections - which can be received by registering your application at https://www.twitch.tv/settings/connections.